# How can I make an object which uses a service as a way of emitting events?

Tags: ballerina

I'm writing a library in Ballerina and I'm looking for a way to emit events, just like the WebSocket's onError, onText etc'...

```
// library code
public type Client object {
    string token;
    http:WebSocketClient? wsConnection = ();
    service eventService;
    public function __init(string clientToken, service clientEventService) {
        self.token = clientToken;
        self.eventService = clientEventService;
        // I can't call any method which is inside the service because I'm not in a type descriptor (?)
    }
};
```

This is what I want to happen on the user's end:

```
Client myClient = new("TOKEN", myEventService);

service myEventService = service {
    resource function onTest(string myText) {
        io:println(myText);
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

**For Ballerina 1.1.x**

There is another way to work with events (more preferred way) in Ballerina, it's a predefined data-structure called `stream`. Please have a look https://ballerina.io/v1-1/learn/by-example/streams.html maybe this may fit your use case.

As far as I know at the moment those standard library `listeners` (such as Web-sub and http) take help from Java interop to help with dispatching calls to those `resource` functions. You can start looking [here](https://github.com/ballerina-platform/ballerina-lang/blob/68a417088cea0eeb1bfbd20d82337f17e07c4202/stdlib/http/src/main/ballerina/src/http/service_endpoint.bal#L29) to learn how Ballerina http library do this.

**For Ballerina 1.2.x**

You will have to implement the observer pattern your self.

Comment: Another issue I've encountered, when opening a websocket connection, the service which is being used can't access the outer class methods and functions, anything I can do about it?

Comment: I didn't understand the "outer class methods" part, can me show me some sample code.

Comment: @AmitKatz Please don't discuss other questions in the comments - instead ask a new question.

Comment: @Dhananjaya After ,looking at stream I've found out that they work completely differently for version 1.2.1 of Ballerina, this is the by example page now https://ballerina.io/v1-2/learn/by-example/streams.html
can you please clarify? maybe it's a different example that I need to look at, there are no methods such as public nor subscribe for the v1.2 stream

Comment: There is an ongoing Ballerina stream revamp, I'm not quite sure what it will look like when it completes, sincerely apologize for pointing to an old resource. With the current implementation you will have to implement your own observer pattern implementation. Updated the answer.

Comment: That's really unfortunate, I don't really know where to begin with the current stream implementation... will I just do a `while true` loop in every observer in a separate worker which will always try to get new data which being pushed to the stream?